# r-ggplot: Y-Axis scale Overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet

Here's the issue: I am trying to plot sales data using ggplot and facet_wrap; however, the scale on y-axis is overlapping. So, I tried to fix it using ***scale_y_discrete*** with ***breaks*** but seems like it is not accurate!
Could anybody help me with the issue?

P.S: I am fairly new to both R, and Stackoverflow, hopefully I correctly followed the guidelines to ask a question!

Below is my code:

```
p <- ggplot(melt(GrossRev_Mnthly, id.vars=c("Month","Sales")), 
            aes(x = Month, y = value, group = Sales, color = Sales)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("January"="Jan", "February"="Feb", "March"="Mar", 
                              "April"="Apr", "June"="Jun", "July"="Jul", "August"="Aug", 
                              "September"="Sep", "October"="Oct", "November"="Nov", 
                              "December"="Dec")) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_y')

p+scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by=100))
```

Below is the tail(24) of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = 
c("January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
"December"), class = "factor"), `North America` = c(30310, 39530, 
41870, 45150, 48330, 51150, 45160, 38970, 32630, 29660, 26150, 
23630, 294318.842921784, 384558.72762734, 406611.767189296, 
432626.777058419,462227.655524398, 485614.555256065, 435224.637726637, 
374164.130572544,313966.373102992, 284206.301762252, 252910.383496192, 
228423.055480594), `South America` = c(1150, 1260, 1350, 1540, 1770, 1680, 
1550,1470, 1380, 1340, 1280, 1170, 2804.54086506681, 3006.79875679876, 
3221.54828127229, 3768.33610512905, 4283.8299558342, 4119.46614133315, 
3793.27221909092, 3528.54360004872, 3224.9723145072, 3123.80357969356, 
2955.06429116269, 2720.26172201782), Europe = c(2860, 4350, 5830, 
7490, 7280, 7220, 7300, 7240, 7050, 5610, 4150, 2560, 52948.8237129747, 
78212.3680413154, 105160.124340346, 134577.240556054, 129995.939392091, 
132308.509679254, 133460.627142569, 133512.445887446, 131669.560099194, 
106958.434894841, 79103.1468531469, 49296.0755206387), Pacific = c(800, 
800, 820, 870, 810, 840, 880, 870, 900, 900, 930, 930, 7736.37723601836, 
7615.91124537093, 7779.28852343473, 8271.66428095236, 7692.29075477023, 
7955.62896635154, 8346.35471651516, 8116.88311688312, 8377.30941853963, 
8411.15211095305, 8700.06736026154, 8690.72767388838), China = c("0", 
"0", "0", "5", "16", "22", "26", "14", "15", "11", "3", "1", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA"), World = c(35120, 45940, 49870, 55055, 58206, 60912, 54916, 
48564, 41975, 37521, 32513, 28291, 357763.584735844, 473393.805670825, 
522772.728334348, 579244.018000554, 604199.715627093, 629998.160043004, 
580824.891804812, 519320.310869229, 457238.214935232, 402699.692347739, 
343668.662000763, 289126.287063806), Sales = c("Mower Unit", 
"Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", 
"Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", "Mower Unit", 
"Mower Unit", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", 
"Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total", 
"Mower Total", "Mower Total", "Mower Total")), .Names = c("Month", 
"North America", "South America", "Europe", "Pacific", "China", 
"World", "Sales"), row.names = 25:48, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Check what happens to your data (`value`) when you use `melt(GrossRev_Mnthly,id.vars=c("Month","Sales"))`, it's not number anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I hard coded few missing values to "NA", and totally forgot about them, that was causing the issue.The code works fine after I replaced "NA" with NA in r to replace missing values.